# Add section news on index cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

What is necessary to do that i load news section on index page? I try this in cakephp 1.3 and my 
**view/elements/latestnews.ctp** looks like

```
<div class="news_span">
<h2><?php __('Latest News'); ?></h2>
<?php
foreach ($news as $news):
    ?>
    <div class="news_span">
        <?php echo $html->link($news['News']['title'], array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'view', $news['News']['slug'])); ?>
        <span class="news_body"><?php echo $text->truncate(strip_tags($news['News']['body'])); ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php
endforeach;
echo $html->link(__('News Archive&hellip;', true), array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'index'), null, null, false);
?>
```

in 
**view/elements/home.ctp** i call

```
<?php echo $this->element('latestNews'); ?>
```

**app/controllers/pages_controller.php** i call in index() function

```
$this->set('news', ClassRegistry::init('News')->find('all', null, 'News.id DESC'));
```

and error is

```
Undefined variable: news [APP/views/elements/latestNews.ctp, line 7]
```

Comment: what is `foreach ($news as $news):` are you a coder ?

Comment: yes, this is `foreach` for news array crate in pages_controller and its work when i go to test.site.com/news.

Comment: please start from learning foreach, that syntax is wrong for even basic coders.

Comment: do you think like this http://www.askaboutphp.com/59/phps-alternative-syntax-and-why-its-useful.html

Comment: check the variable $news which you are using again is wrong, you are using that for what reason. In the attached link it is `$sites as $site` not `$sites as $sites`

Comment: ok, i try now `foreach ($newses as $news):` same effect , i also change in controller 
`        $news_data = ClassRegistry::init('News');
        $add_news = $news_data->find('list');
        $this->set('newses', $news_data->find('list'));`

Comment: use `pr($variable);` to debug what you are values you are getting in your `views/controller/models`
Initially you used all now list both are pretty different from each other

Comment: aha, i get array of news like its should be i think you help me some other output variable redirect to controller => view and not index so on view i don't have news at all.

Comment: yes going thru code i notice this so  `$page = $this->Page->find(array('Page.path' => 'home_' . $this->Session->read('Config.language')));` and that was call home_en-us.ctp which not same as home.ctp where i have news elements , thank you any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to an element through the element’s second argument:

```
<?php echo $this->element('latestNews', $news); ?>
```

[Reference](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element)